# Perl output shows on the left side of terminal?

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu-10.04

Strangely when I execute a code in Perl, the output always appears on the left side of my command line. For example.

```
admin@admin-machine:~$ perl my_program
1 2 3 4 5 admin@admin-machine:~$
```

How do I get it to show output on a line by itself like the following?

```
admin@admin-machine:~$ perl my_program
1 2 3 4 5
admin@admin-machine:~$
```

Comment: You'll never get that output (without manually positioning the cursor). The stuff to the right of the prompt is what the user enters.

Comment: Technically, it's possible: `perl -we 'fork and exit; sleep 1; print "$_ " for 1..5; '`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a newline (\n) to the end of your print statements. E.g.

```
print "1 2 3 4 5 \n";
```

Comment: or just use `say "1 2 3 4 5";`

Answer (score 2):

Everything is possible assuming you really know what you're doing.

```
if(0 == fork()) {
        sleep(1);
        print "1 2 3 4 5";
}

s0me0ne@ws:/tmp$ perl print.pl 
s0me0ne@ws:/tmp$ 1 2 3 4 5
```

I doubt if it helps someone but... Just answering ;)

Comment: Note that this answers the literal question that was originally asked. However, I fixed the question to correspond to the accepted answer and voted up this answer. I am leaving this note so as to try and avoid others downvoting it.